# How to retrieve the label text as per the html provided?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Sometimes I failed to get the inner text of a web-element; recently working on thePersonal insurance, and failed to get inner text of label (web element). Here are the script and screenshot of webpage inspected:

```
WebElement detailPostCode =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='q_codePostalDetailAU']"));
System.out.println("postcode label text "+detailPostCode.getText());
```

Could any please help me understand the problem. Thank you for your kind concern.

[image: screenshot of the page-inspection view of the webelement]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you add a tag to your question for the language you are using. Also format the code in your question as code. See the help topics if you need help with formatting.

Comment: Can you please add the (full/relevant) error message or describe what happens when it doesn't work? It looks like your locator is good... I'm wondering if it isn't a timing issue where you need to add a wait. Have you tried a wait? If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the `<label>` with text as **Postal code** is a *child node* of the `<div>` tag with *class* attribute as **q_codePostal**.

### What went wrong?

As per your code trial you have used:

```
WebElement detailPostCode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='q_codePostalDetailAU']"));
```

In this expression `//label[@for='q_codePostalDetailAU']` will always refer to the descending `<input>` tag with `id` attribute as **q_codePostalDetailAU**. Hence your code trial didn't work.

### Solution

As an alternative you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement detailPostCode = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.q_codePostal>label"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='q_codePostal']/label"));
```

Comment: It is working now with the xpath you have suggested... but, I didn't get what is that making the difference. Could you please explain me the reason?

Comment: "for" is not really an attribute that you can use in your xpath, if it was class, id, css, text , then you could have done it that way. I always prefer to use the parent div(if available ) and navigate from their to the child tags, its easier that way and hard to miss it , 99% of the time always work. Also you can upvote my answer if you liked it. Hope my answer helped. cheers!